# No emacs package on rpmforge (RHEL)

Tags: emacs, redhat, rpm, yum

When trying to install emacs on RHEL 5.5, I get the following error:

```
 $ sudo yum install emacs
 Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
 This system is not registered with RHN.
 RHN support will be disabled.
 Setting up Install Process
 No package emacs available.
 Nothing to do
```

I've already install rpmforge.
When I try searching for emacs, I get the following:

```
================================================= Matched: emacs ==================================================
crm114-emacs.x86_64 : Emacs mode for CRM114
ed.x86_64 : The GNU line editor.
emacs-git.x86_64 : Git version control system support for Emacs
emacs-ocaml.x86_64 : Emacs mode for Objective Caml
gpm.i386 : A mouse server for the Linux console.
gpm.x86_64 : A mouse server for the Linux console.
ne.x86_64 : Nice editor
perl-Games-Dissociate.noarch : Dissociated Press algorithm and filter
ratpoison.x86_64 : Ratpoison window manager
readline.i386 : A library for editing typed command lines.
readline.x86_64 : A library for editing typed command lines.
sylpheed.x86_64 : Full-featured GTK+ based fast e-mail client
texmacs.x86_64 : Structured WYSIWYG scientific text editor
```

Where can I find emacs? (or do I have to download and compile from the source?) Thanks

Comment: None of the package descriptions looks like it is for Emacs.  Besides, this question wouldn't qualify for programming question.  It better be asked at RedHat/Fedora part of the SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running RHEL, you need to register the system with RedHat via the `rhn_register` command. See http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.4/html/Reference_Guide/ch-register.html for more details on how to do this.

Once this has been done, you may successfully use `yum update`, `yum install ...` etc.